# Activate javascript function with parameter after button click

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

```js
function changeForms(data){
     document.getElementById("firstname").value = data.firstName;
     document.getElementById("lastname").value = data.lastName;
     document.getElementById("email").value = data.emailAddress;   
    }
```

I want to call this function with this button:

```html
<button class="button" id="autofill" onclick="">Fill</button>
```

My problem is, that the parameter data is from another function, but i dont want to call the changeForms function after the function getData like below:

```js
function getData(data) {
     data= data.values[0];
        changeForms(data);
    }
```

I want to start the function changeForms after the click, but with the data from getData.
Is it possible to stop a function until a buttonclick or maybe store the data somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Marcel

Comment: Not sure where exactly the problem lies. Are you concerned with ensuring that the data has been retrieved (for example, via ajax)? If that's the case, simply have the ajax function's success create the "fill" button.

Comment: Need a little more clarity as to what you are wanting to do. Where is the 'data' coming from?

Comment: in the snippet I call the function changeForms with the function getData. But I want to call the function changeForms with the button, but with the data from getData

Comment: what about an onclick listener, changeForms( getData(data) ) -- Of course, then the getData() would simply RETURN the data to the changeForms function...

Comment: when do you call getData() then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first suggestion don't do inline javascript, this looks ugly, hard to maintain and not that flexible.

I suggest:

add to your button an id, like "buttonWithId" then write following javascript code:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("buttonWithId");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   // your code goes here....
});
```

here some docu on this:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

then you allway can use the return value of your `getData``

```
var getData = function() {
    return someData;
}
```

then the call looks like this:

```
var someData = getData();
changeForms(someData);
```

put this inside the empty function defined earlier.

Note: if your function `getData` is async, you have to use a callback function or a promise (my personal favorite choice).